# How to adjust table name in Kotlin Exposed on runtime

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-exposed

We are using database table names which are prefixed with environment names e.g:
instead of just '**Cities**' we have '**ci_Cities**', '**dev_Cities**' and '**prod_Cities**'.

The problem is that Schema definitions are based on Kotlin objects, which is nice in an usage, but doesn't allow me to simply inject table prefix in e.g. constructor.

So the question is how to implement such a functionality in Kotlin-Exposed?

Comment: Please check comments of [this issue](https://github.com/JetBrains/Exposed/issues/672)

Comment: The main thing in solving above problem is that it is not possible to easily provide value from outside world. Because Schema are objects you can not provide current environment variable in easy and clean way to that Schema object. Setting value on the object is awful and also simply doesn't work: when Table() constructor is started tableName is already called as a part of initialization. How should I initialize internalTableName with value from e.g. Spring @Value("someproperty")?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the end I have found solution, which seems to be quite elegant.
But I think, that some improvements could be done also in Kotlin Exposed, so that in most cases solution is more concise.

City.kt

```
data class City(val id: Int, val name: String, val timestamp: Instant)
```

Schema.kt

```
import org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.ResultRow
import org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.Table
import org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.`java-time`.timestamp

class CitiesSchema(environment: String) {
    val cities = CitiesTable(environment)
}

class CitiesTable(environment: String) : Table(environment + "_Cities") {
    val id = varchar("id", 99)
    val name = varchar("name", 99)
    val timestamp = timestamp("timestamp")
}
```

CitiesRepository.kt

```
class CitiesRepository(dataSource: DataSource, private val schema: CitiesSchema) {
    private val database = Database.connect(dataSource).defaultFetchSize(10000)

    override fun save(city: City): City {
        transaction(database) {
            schema.cities.insert {
                it[schema.cities.id] = city.id
                it[schema.cities.name] = city.name
                it[schema.cities.timestamp] = city.timestamp
            }
        }
        return city
    }
```

Then in e.g. Spring you can instantiate your schema:

```
@Bean
public CitiesSchema schema(@Value("${spring.application.env}") String environment) {
    return new CitiesSchema(environment);
}
```

It would be nice to have in Kotlin Exposed ability to rename tables/columns on runtime. Then it would be possible to access Kotlin objects without additional ceremonies.
Such a feature could look like in Jooq:
https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.14/manual-single-page/#settings-render-mapping